# TestNG ERROR No test suite found. Nothing to run

Tags: bash, command-line, testng

I have a problem with run test suite from command line.

```
java -jar test.jar

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user01/jenkins/run_suite/test-suites/test.xml  (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:167)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:302)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:991)
[TestNG] [ERROR] No test suite found. Nothing to run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
```

but if I look in directory

```
[user01@xxxx ~]$ ll /home/user01/jenkins/run_suite/test-suites/test.xml
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 user01 user01 233 Apr  7 16:07 /home/user01/jenkins/run_suite/test-suites/test.xml
```

I've changed permission to 777

```
chmod -R 777 /home/user01/jenkins/
```

but does not help. The same test.xml suite is executed without problems from eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue :)

Because my file "test.xml" was updated by

```
sed -i 's/\(testSuite = \)/\1test-suites\/test_suite.xml/' test.xml
```

I notice that I have white space on last line, after I've removed space issue gone, so I run following command

```
sed -i 's/\s*$//' test.xml
```

working now :)